# JBoss Wildfly - Scheduler

Tags: jboss7.x, schedule, wildfly

I know how to make and work with a Scheduled job in Wildfly as such:

```java
@Stateless
public class MyTasks{

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "5")
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("helo world!");
    }
}
```

How do I update the timer or execute this schedule immediately without having to update the code.  In JBoss 4, using MBeans and the JMX console I could change the timer and execute the job whenever.  Is there something or somewhere that allows me access this task?

What I would ideally like is something like below:

```java
@ManagedBean
public class ManagedTask{

    public void executeTask() {
        //Not valid
       MyTasks mytasks = new MyTasks();
      mytasks.setTimer(...):
      mytasks.do work();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Stateless
public class MyTasks {

    @Resource
    private javax.ejb.TimerService timerService;

    public void scheduleTimer() {
        // Pick from a number of createTimer methods. This one expires in 5 seconds
        Timer nextTimer = timerService.createTimer(5000, null);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("helo world!");
    }
}
```